# Best practice for ajax post in Struts?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, struts

I have found some examples but I don't get it. Here is one of them;

```
function submitForm() {
        $('#submitMail').attr('action', '<s:url action="submitMail" />?user=<%=request.getAttribute("user")%>');
        $('#submitMail').submit();
        return false;
    }


<s:form action="submitMail" method="post">
....
<button type="button" onclick="submitForm();">
</s:form>
```

What is the best for post in Struts?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks clarity;  However if you are looking for ajax submission of your form, you can try using jquery . Please see this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You can pass additional data as well.

If you are looking for ajax submission using struts specific tags,
you can use `struts2-jquery` .

see this :https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SubmitTag

Hope this helps. If you encounter problem while using this, please share the details of where you are struck, so that we can help you.